# How does auditd get notified that the current audit.log is at its max size?

Tags: linux-audit

We recently realized that our current configuration for auditd was causing our /var/log/audit filesystem to become full so I started to play around with the /etc/audit/auditd.conf file to try to fix that. I modified the conf file to look like this:

```
#
# This file controls the configuration of the audit daemon
#

log_file = /var/log/audit/audit.log
log_format = RAW
log_group = root
priority_boost = 4
flush = INCREMENTAL
freq = 20
num_logs = 4
disp_qos = lossy
dispatcher = /sbin/audispd
name_format = NONE
##name = mydomain
max_log_file = 4
max_log_file_action = ROTATE
space_left = 75
space_left_action = email
action_mail_acct = root
admin_space_left = 50
admin_space_left_action = halt
disk_full_action = SUSPEND
disk_error_action = SUSPEND
##tcp_listen_port =
tcp_listen_queue = 5
tcp_max_per_addr = 1
##tcp_client_ports = 1024-65535
tcp_client_max_idle = 0
enable_krb5 = no
krb5_principal = auditd
##krb5_key_file = /etc/audit/audit.key
```

But the files in /var/log/audit are still becoming larger than what is set in max_log_file (size in MB)

```
root@my-server:~# ls -lah /var/log/audit/
total 18M
drwx------  3 root root   3.0K Apr 22 13:17 .
drwxrwxr-x 12 root syslog 4.0K Apr 22 03:13 ..
-rw-------  1 root root   4.2M Apr 22 13:35 audit.log
-r--------  1 root root   4.1M Apr 22 13:17 audit.log.1
-r--------  1 root root   4.0M Apr 22 11:22 audit.log.2
-r--------  1 root root   5.0M Apr 22 11:39 audit.log.3
drwx------  2 root root    12K Feb  4 10:44 lost+found
```

The one that is 4.0M I rotated manually by running auditd by itself. While troubleshooting this it lead me to wonder, **what is watching this directory that sends the notification to auditd to rotate the logs when the current audit.log is at the maximum size?** The only process that's running that I found that I think could be doing that is

```
root      149689  0.0  0.2  11580  2568 ?        S<sl 11:43   0:00 /sbin/auditd -n
```

But it doesn't seem to be working how I think it should.

Comment: `-h` would say around `4.1M`, it should be `4194304` or a few hundreds more or less, which seems OK for the 3 newer files. The older file, could be created before you change the configuration, are you sure it's not? After waiting for some time, do all go to `~4.1`?

Comment: Also auditd is watching its log dir, I don't think there is anyone in the middle..

Comment: @thanasisp - I let it sit over the weekend and the same audit.log that was at 4.2M has now grown to 6.7M, I was hoping I was just being impatient with it. I'm thinking I must have it misconfigured somewhere.